# Saving Google Sign-In User Information to Database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, oauth, google-api

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC application and have successfully implemented Google sign-in using OAuth. However, I'm struggling with saving the user information from Google to my own database. Below is a simplified version of my code:

```
public IActionResult GoogleLogIn()
{
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = Url.Action("GoogleResponse"),
    };

    return Challenge(properties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleResponse()
{
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    var clamis = result.Principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault().Claims.Select(
        claim => new
        {
            claim.Issuer,
            claim.OriginalIssuer,
            claim.Type,
            claim.Value
        }
        );

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Problem:
After a user successfully signs in with Google, I want to save their information (e.g., user ID, email, name) to my database. Could someone guide me on the best practices and provide a code example for achieving this in ASP.NET MVC?
Additional Information:

Using ASP.NET MVC framework.
Have the necessary client ID and client secret from the Google Developer Console.
Database is [mention your database type and version].
Any help or guidance on the proper way to handle this process would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Implemented Google sign-in using Owin.Security.Google.
Need assistance with extracting and saving user information to my database.

Comment: Can you handle data through google? I mean that if the function you have in your controller does capture the data you are looking for.